# What is the expected behaviour of initialization using polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

This should be a simple 100-level question, but I'm seeing something I don't expect in my project, and web searches have failed me, so I thought I'd ask here. Suppose I have the following C++ code:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
  BaseClass() { 
    this->Initialize(); 
  }

  int foo() {
    return this->foo_;
  }

protected:
  virtual int GetInitialValue() { 
    return 1; 
  }

private:
  void Initialize() {
    this->foo_ = this->GetInitialValue();
  }

  int foo_;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
  DerivedClass() : BaseClass() {
  }

protected:
  virtual int GetInitialValue() { 
    return 2; 
  }
};
```

What should be the return value of `DerivedClass::foo()`? Will `BaseClass::GetInitialValue()` ever get called, or will it always be `DerivedClass::GetInitialValue()` that gets called? Where should I have searched, and what search terms should I have used to find the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>`GetInitialValue()` isn't virtual so there isn't dynamic dispatch anyway.</strike>

In your situation, the expected value of `foo()` would be `1`, as the value of `_foo` is set in the `BaseClass` constructor. The derived class's version isn't called as the `BaseClass` constructor is called first, and the `DerivedClass` members haven't been initialized yet.

This is also item #9 in [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), and that snippet is in this page from artima:

http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

The summary from that article is:

> > **Things to Remember**
> >
> > Don't call virtual functions during construction or destruction, because such calls will never go to a more derived class than that of the currently executing constructor or destructor

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
   public:
   Base() { this->initialize(); }
   void initialize() { this->_foo = this->getInitial(); }
   virtual int getInitial() { return 1; }

   int _foo;
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
      Derived() : Base() {}
      virtual int getInitial() { return 2;}
};


int main()
{
   Base* dp = new Derived();
   std::cout << dp->_foo << std::endl;
}
```

This code outputs `1`.

Comment: Please see comment to previous answer. The sample source code was incorrect. It now correctly contains virtual as part of the declaration of GetInitialValue().

Comment: During constructors and destructors, virtual functions are dispatched but to the constructed/destructed type. In deeper hierarchies that can make a difference.

Comment: @JimEvans - Revised my answer a little, but your code edit only changes the first sentence of my response.

Comment: This explains the behaviour I'm seeing in my project. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed a problem with your code. You're indirectly calling `virtual` function from constructor which is very very bad bad idea.

Read this article by Scott Meyers :

[Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html)

Also read this FAQ:

[When my base class's constructor calls a virtual function on its this object, why doesn't my derived class's override of that virtual function get invoked?](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5)

Comment: Good catch; that's an oversight. I've edited the sample code to now correctly contain virtual functions.

Comment: @JimEvans: Now see my complete answer!

Comment: There's another part to the question: Given the code above, if I call `new DerivedClass()`, will `BaseClass::GetInitialValue()` ever get called?

Comment: This is incorrect.  `foo_` should always be 1 because at the point of the base class constructor, the derived class "part" is not yet initialized.  See `birryree`'s answer.

Comment: @Andre: Yeah. I noticed that as well. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz, this is wrong. It prints `1`. Test your code before posting :)

Comment: @Nikolai: What? At the time when you posted your comment, did you notice I've edited my post?

Comment: @Nikolai: I think I had edited my post 4 minutes *before* your comment. :D

Comment: Well, I don't hit refresh button every second. Don't sweat it :)

Answer (score 2):

During the execution of constructors and destructors, the dynamic type is the constructed/destructed type, so in this case, the dispatch won't be to the derived version.  In something like

```
struct Base {
   virtual void f() { std::cout << "Base::f()\n"; }
};

struct D1: Base {
   D1() { f(); }
   virtual void f() { std::cout << "D1::f()\n"; }
};

struct D2: D1 {
   D2() { name = "D2";
   virtual void f() { std::cout << name << "::f()\n"; }
   std::string name;
};
```

the construction of an object of type D2 display "D1::f()" because the call the f() occurs during the construction of the D1 base.

To understand the reason, consider what would happen if D2::f() was called, the name member isn't constructed yet...

Answer (score 0):

The process is like this :

1) The constructor or Derives is called

2) It calls the base class constructor

3) The base class constructor sets ist vtable

4) The base class constructor body is executed (in this constructor, base class vtable is used)

5) The derives constructor sets it vtable

6) The constructor is called, at this (in this constructor, the derives vtable i used)

Google: c++ virtual method constructor

For example: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Otherwise, you could search in the C++ standard draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/#mailing2011-02) 12.7 4

"When a virtual function is called […] from a constructor […] or from a destructor, and the objct to which the call applies is the object under construction or destruction the function called in the one defined in the constructor or destrutor's own class or in one of its bases but not a function overriding in a class derived"

Answer (score 0):

I know I should be answering the question myself, but I can't do better than this:

Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction
http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Quote from that article:

During base class construction, virtual functions never go down into derived classes. Instead, the object behaves as if it were of the base type. Informally speaking, during base class construction, virtual functions aren't.